# How to append sqlldr log file?

Tags: bash, sql-loader

I connect to sqlldr via bash script and I want to log my results to existing file `-${LOGFILE}.log`. But sqlldr overwrites this file while I want to it to append. Is there any append option for sqlldr or maybe some workaround?

```
${ORACLE_BIN}/sqlldr ${CONNECTION} control=${SCRIPTPATH}/${SQLLDR_CONTROLFILE}.ctl data=${BATCHFILE} log=${LOGFILE}.log
```

thanks

Comment: For a bash-only solution we need to know what OS you use.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet Linux, but I will need it for Solaris too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if it will work on Solaris but named pipes are an option under GNU/Linux:

```
$ mkfifo a=rw /tmp/sqlldr.pipe
$ cat /tmp/sqlldr.pipe >> ${LOGFILE}.log &
$ ${ORACLE_BIN}/sqlldr ... log=/tmp/sqlldr.pipe
```

`sqlldr` will write its log to the opened named pipe while `cat`, in the background, will append the named pipe to your log file. Important: `cat` terminates when `sqlldr` terminates. So, you will have to relaunch `cat` before each invocation of `sqlldr`.